# What is the score used to visualize attention in this paper?

Tags: natural-language-processing, papers, implementation, dialogue-systems

I'm reading this paper [Global-Locally Self-Attentive Dialogue State Tracker](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P18-1135.pdf) and follow through the implementation published in [GLAD](https://github.com/salesforce/glad).

I was wondering if someone can clarify what variable or score is used to calculate the global and local self-attention scores in Figure 4 (the heatmap).

For me, it is not really clear how to derive these scores. The only score that would match the given dimension would be in the scoring module  $p_{utt}=softmax(a_{utt})$. However, I do not see in their implementation that anything is done with this value.

So, what I did was the following:

```
 q_utts = []
 a_utts=[]
 for c_val in C_vals:
     q_utt, a_utt = attend(H_utt, c_val.unsqueeze(0).expand(len(batch), *c_val.size()), lens=utterance_len)
     q_utts.append(q_utt)
     a_utts.append(a_utt)
attention_score= torch.mean(torch.stack(a_utts,dim=1),dim=1)
```

But the resulting attention score differs very much from what I expect.